# Is a C# struct with a single field equivalent to the standalone type of the field in unmanaged memory?

Tags: c#, unmanaged

For example, is the unmanged memory layout of this struct:

```cs
public struct MyStruct<T>
  where T: unmanaged
{
    public T pointer;
}
```

the same as a plain `T`?

Also, does they behave in the same way when calling `Marshal.PtrToStructure` and `Marshal.StructureToPtr`?
That is, will this work?

```cs
MyStruct<int> myStruct;
IntPtr pointer = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(MyStruct<int>));
Marshal.StructureToPtr(myStruct, pointer, false);
int myStructField = Marshal.PtrToStructure<int>(pointer);
```

Comment: Even if the answer is yes today, don't you run the risk it changes with a new version of the compiler. I don't think memory layout is guaranteed to stay the same, aka it isn't part of the API contract.

Comment: @rene Then will adding `[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]` and the `[FieldOffset(0)]` do the job?

Comment: It is the same, yes.  Layout only starts playing a role when a struct has more than one member.  Don't worry about that changing, the ultimate arbiter are the people that design processors and they are a very conservative lot.  Thank heavens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is theoretically dependent on which build of the CLR you have. Generally yes, in managed memory a struct is represented by a sequential set of fields. However, especially with local variables, individual fields may be placed into registers or other places (or even optimized away), and with multiple fields reordering may also happen.

And you can never rely on a particular implementation not changing from version to version.

Theoretically, a conforming implementation of the CLR is free to arrange memory in any way it sees fit. **My private implementation of .NET stores data on the moon, which is made of cheese.** (The stack is made of pizza boxes with hand-written notes, in case you were wondering).

---

As far as interop is concerned, structs are **always** marshalled in a defined way. The `StructLayoutAttribute` is respected: it is part of the specification and not likely to change. Note that if you do not specify the attribute then the CLR is free to reorder or repack it, which is why you should **always** specify it for interop code.

So if you specify `LayoutKind.Sequential` then the fields will be aligned beginning at offset 0, and packed according to the bitness of the application (or as specified).